std::mdspan support in MSVC (19.41) VS (17.11.5)
Why this code doesn’t compile with MSVC 19.41 / VS 17.11.5
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mdspan>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    auto array2d = std::mdspan(v.data(), 2, 4);

    std::cout << array2d[1, 1];
}

while the Compiler support for C++23 says that std::mdspan is supported starting from the MSVC (19.39) VS (17.9)?
The error message is
<source>(11): error C2676: binary '[': 'std::mdspan<_Ty,std::extents<_IndexType,18446744073709551615,18446744073709551615>,std::layout_right,std::default_accessor<_Ty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
        with
        [
            _Ty=int,
            _IndexType=size_t
        ]
Z:/compilers/msvc/14.41.33923-14.41.33923.0/include\mdspan(1338): note: could be 'int &std::mdspan<_Ty,std::extents<_IndexType,18446744073709551615,18446744073709551615>,std::layout_right,std::default_accessor<_Ty>>::operator [](const std::array<_OtherIndexType,2> &) noexcept(<expr>) const'
        with
        [
            _Ty=int,
            _IndexType=size_t
        ]
<source>(11): note: 'int &std::mdspan<_Ty,std::extents<_IndexType,18446744073709551615,18446744073709551615>,std::layout_right,std::default_accessor<_Ty>>::operator [](const std::array<_OtherIndexType,2> &) noexcept(<expr>) const': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::array<_OtherIndexType,2> &' from 'int'
        with
        [
            _Ty=int,
            _IndexType=size_t
        ]
Z:/compilers/msvc/14.41.33923-14.41.33923.0/include\mdspan(1330): note: or       'int &std::mdspan<_Ty,std::extents<_IndexType,18446744073709551615,18446744073709551615>,std::layout_right,std::default_accessor<_Ty>>::operator [](std::span<_OtherIndexType,2>) noexcept(<expr>) const'
        with
        [
            _Ty=int,
            _IndexType=size_t
        ]
<source>(11): note: 'int &std::mdspan<_Ty,std::extents<_IndexType,18446744073709551615,18446744073709551615>,std::layout_right,std::default_accessor<_Ty>>::operator [](std::span<_OtherIndexType,2>) noexcept(<expr>) const': could not deduce template argument for 'std::span<_OtherIndexType,2>' from 'int'
        with
        [
            _Ty=int,
            _IndexType=size_t
        ]

The same issue with the example code from std::mdspan.
Am I correct that the issue is that despite the fact they implemented the std::mdspan, MSVC still have no support for the multidimensional operator[] language feature? If so, what is the value of supporting std::mdspan without it?

Yep, still not implemented https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Multi-argument-operator/10306063
